# OnePlus 3 & Oneplus 5 viewport size for chrome Emulated Devices

Tags: google-chrome, frontend, web-testing, ui-design, oneplusthree

I wanted to add OnePlus 3 and OnePlus 5 as custom devices in the emulated devices list of Google Chrome. Please provide the viewport size so that I can test my website with it.

Example for pixel 2 display dimentions

[image: emulator]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 11):

I was searching for the same thing and I found this: 
 https://www.mydevice.io/

**OnePlus 5:** `455x809`, pixel ratio `2.375`, user agent `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; Build/OPM1.171019.011) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.158 Mobile Safari/537.36`

I don't have an OnePlus 3 and I didn't found anything related.

Comment: Annoyingly, no OnePlus devices are listed on that site now.

Answer (score 2):

OnePlus 3:
412x732, pixel ratio: 2.625

Comment: On my OnePlus 3, I went to a website that confirms these dimensions. I haven't confirmed the pixel ratio. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/x8ZlYsH.jpg) of the dimensions.

Comment: seems incorrect, checked on real device and in chrome with provided settings https://ibb.co/p3j4v0x

Answer (score 0):

The OnePlus 3 uses a 346x535. Not a standard one as far as I can see, with all the consequences it brings in.