# Viewport of various devices

Tags: frontend, viewport

Hey I need to figure the viewport of the devices for OnePlus 5T. Anyone has the specs for that particular phone? I have tried using browser stack to find the specs for other phones and there are a few phones where the viewports are not available.

Comment: I think same question is asked here: [OnePlus 3 & Oneplus 5 viewport size for chrome Emulated Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50207552/oneplus-3-oneplus-5-viewport-size-for-chrome-emulated-devices)

Comment: hey yeah i saw that but I need it specific for oneplus 5T

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got from [OnePlus forum](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/emulate-oneplus-5t-in-chrome.715479/).

resolution: 412x800

dppx(pixel ratio): 2.63

User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; ONEPLUS A5010 Build/OPM1.171019.011) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Mobile Safari/537.36